# Why am I getting out of date or slightly incorrect data back from the Linked in API when querying for job listings of a certain company?

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api

Using PHP and Curl, I've successfully gotten through the OAuth process to gain a token using the Linkedin API. When making an API call to get a listing of a specific company's job listings I get truncated and incorrect information back. I'm only getting 5 of the 7 job listings and one of them doesn't even exist when looking at the job listings on linkedin.com.

I've determined that this is not some caching issue on my side because my application data matches the data given by this tool: https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

This is the API call I'm making:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{COMPANY_ID}/updates?event-type=job-posting&format=json

I think I may be using the wrong API call as it looks like I'm only getting updates and not the complete list of jobs. I can't find any other way to query for jobs though.

Comment: I'll answer my own question here. Yes I was using the wrong API. The jobs API is what is needed and you need to apply to be a Linkedin developer partner in order to get access to it.